# Arranging imagebuttons in 2d circle layout with no animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android app and I need to have a dropdown button from which the user will change the layout bellow it to have N ImageButtons arranged in a circle (from 14 to 24 buttons) in which the buttons will touch each other. There won't be any animation just a standing buttons with a click listener to every one of them. Let me describe it as a bracelet

[image]

I've developed the app but not with a buttons arranged in circle, so I have the functionality. I've searched around and found [CircleLayout of dimitry-zaitsev](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout), but it has a minSDK = 18 . While I think that what I need could be achieved in less. I also found 3D Carousel but I need a simple 2d arrangement. I don't mind if the solution will be 10 layout files with the respective number of buttons from 14-24 or if the buttons are generated programatically.

Could someone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded in building the solution of my problem. I did it by using parts of the ideas of this library: [Android-CircleMenu](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu) I hope this will help others who struggle in building circle layout.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`ArcLayout`](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout) library. You will probably be able to do that with it.

Comment: I'll take a look while I'm waiting for another answer.